# Why Python Multiprocess class doesn't change the attribute?

Tags: python, multiprocess

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from multiprocessing import Process

class Signprocess(Process):
  """docstring for SignThread"""
  def __init__(self):
    super(SignThread, self).__init__()
    self.result = False


  def run(self):
    self.result = True
    print 123

process= Signprocess()
print process.result
process.start()
print process.result
process.join()
print process.result
```

Here is the output

```
False
False
123
False
```

It's really strange, output `123` indicates that `run()` method is actually executed, but `result` attribute is never set to `True`, Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Process` represents a forked process, not a thread. After the `fork` occurs (before `self.result = True` is executed), the memory space becomes unlinked; changes in one process do not affect the other process unless explicitly performed on shared memory or the results are communicated via some other form of IPC. Read more of the `multiprocessing` documentation; it provides many different ways to communicate data back and forth, but plain Python object state is not one of those ways.

Alternatively, if the goal is to use threads, not processes, change the import line to `from multiprocessing.dummy import Process`, which gets you the `multiprocessing` API backed by threads, not processes; threads share memory space, so you would see your expected result, though in computationally expensive threading cases, you would not gain much from parallelism due to CPython's GIL.